# Polynomial And Quadratic equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree grater than 2. If $p(x)$ leaves a remainder $a$ and $-a$ when divided by $x+a$ and $x-a$ respectively, then what is the remainder when $p(x)$ is divided by $x^2-a^2$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be divided by x^2-a^2??

Comment: I edited it to reflect that. If the OP objects, please let us know!

Comment: oh sry my bad its x^2 -a^2

Comment: solution plzz ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the two conditions give $p(-a)=a$ and $p(a)=-a$.

Writing the Euclidian division $p(x)=(x^2-a^2)\,q(x) + r(x)$ the remainder $r(x)$ must be a $1^{st}$ degree polynomial $r(x)=r_1x + r_2$. Evaluate the division equation at $x = \pm a$ to determine $r_1,r_2$.

Comment: can u explain how do i evaluate the equation at +-a thanks..

Comment: For $+a$ for example: $p(a)=(a^2-a^2)q(a) + r(a)$ which reduces to $-a = r_1 \cdot a + r_2$.

Comment: sry but i cant makeout whats written

Comment: @user383808 You take the division $p(x)=(x^2-a^2)q(x) + r(x)$ and substitute $x=a$. The term $(a^2-a^2)q(a)$ is obviously 0, which leaves $p(a)=r(a)$. You know that $p(a)=-a$, and $r(a)=r_1 \cdot a + r_2$ so in the end you have $-a = r_1 \cdot a + r_2$. Repeat the above for $x=-a$ and you get a 2nd equation in $r_1,r_2$. Solve the system of two equations (in this particular case you can simply add and subtract them) and you get $r_1,r_2$. More hint: $r_1=-1,r_2=0$.

Comment: got the answer  thanks bro..